# Use another class for user login in Django

Tags: python, django, class, authentication

I would like to login and manage user with my own class, and not with the one provided by Django.

This is the code to define the user class in my `module.py`:

```
class ClientManager(models.Manager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, first_name, last_name):
        users = get_user_model()
        users.objects.create_superuser(email, password, first_name, last_name)

    def get_by_natural_key(self, first_name, last_name):
        return self.get(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)



class Client(models.Model, UserManager):
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'password',)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    first_name = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    last_name = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    email = models.TextField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    password = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    objects = ClientManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_natural_key(self):
        return [self.first_name, self.last_name]
```

But when I do `django manage.py createsuperuser` it says (after ask me for the email):

```
TypeError: get_by_natural_key() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'MyApp.Client'` in `settings.py`

I read the documentation but I didn't understand what I have to do. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have your auth model set to `oCMSapp.Designer` and your model manager set to `DesignerManager()`, yet neither of those are shown here?

Comment: Sorry, I just edit the post.

Comment: If you're trying to make a custom user model, I would take a look at the documentation. Your configuration is a little off. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/

Comment: Why is your model inheriting from a manager? That makes no sense.